# How to make C# function as following

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

How could I change this piece of code to a function with parameters?

My variables are:

1. ClientsTbl
2. ClCode
3. gridView
4. Tables.ClientsTbl
5. txtbx

Code:

```
string sql = "SELECT *";
sql += "FROM ClientsTbl ";
sql += " Order By ClCode";

gridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
string jsonTbl = GetJsonFromSql(sql);
List<db.Tables.ClientsTbl> localsal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<db.Tables.ClientsTbl>>(jsonTbl);
gridView.DataSource = localsal;

txtbx.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in gridView.Rows
              where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString())
              select Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[1].FormattedValue)).Count().ToString();
txtbx.Text = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("id-ID"), "{0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse(txtbx.Text));
```

I trying to use this code:

```
public static void gvLoad (string tbl, string pk, DataGridView gridView, TextBox txtbx)
{
    string sql = "SELECT *";
    sql += "FROM " + tbl + "";
    sql += " Order By " + pk + "";

    gridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    string jsonTbl = GetJsonFromSql(sql);
    List<db.Tables.ClientsTbl> localsal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<db.Tables.ClientsTbl>>(jsonTbl);
    gridView.DataSource = localsal;

    txtbx.Text = (from DataGridViewRow row in gridView.Rows
                  where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString())
                  select Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[1].FormattedValue)).Count().ToString();
    txtbx.Text = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("id-ID"), "{0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse(txtbx.Text));
}
```

but I don't know how to make parameter for `Tables.ClientsTbl`.

Any help please?

Comment: Table name cannot be parameterized.

Comment: Also, it's a mistake to automate loading full tables like this. Think instead about making it easier to load only the records you need at the times you need them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the stored procedure to [concat and execute sql dynamicly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) if you are using the Microsoft SQL Server database.
for example:

```
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TblName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SortKey VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SortType BIT = 0
-- other parameters definition
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @Columns + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TblName) + ' WHERE 1=1 ' -- replace 1=1 to your filter condition
IF @SortType = 0
  BEGIN
   SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, ' ORDER BY ' + @SortKey + 'ASC')
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
   SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql, ' ORDER BY ' + @SortKey + 'DESC')
  END
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

or you can use EF + Linq + some package like mapper